# How to test a Post with input param in Json without using JsonFormatter

Tags: c#, rest, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

How can Json data be defined in unit tester without using objects?

This works defining an object and then passing it as an input parameter:

```
SRSWebAPI.Models.DeptsAndBelowRateInput objDeptsAndBelowRateInput = new DeptsAndBelowRateInput();
List<DeptIdModel> lstDept = new List<DeptIdModel>();
lstDept.Add(new DeptIdModel() {DeptId = "1234"});
lstDept.Add(new DeptIdModel() { DeptId = "1222" });

objDeptsAndBelowRateInput.DeptIdList = new List<DeptIdModel>();
objDeptsAndBelowRateInput.DeptIdList.AddRange(lstDept);


System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter();

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
{
    var answ = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DeptsAndBelowRate>();

    Assert.IsNotNull(answ);
    Assert.IsNotNull(answ.Result);
    //Assert.True(answ.Result);
}
```

However, I would prefer to just pass json data and not reference an object but the following does not work:

```
var theContent2 = new StringContent(@"
   {""DeptsAndBelowRateInput"": {
    ""RequestName"": ""AspGroup"",
    ""ReportstoDeptAs"": ""Assigned"",
    ""TrendType"": ""LostWorkDayCaseRate"",
    ""BudgetMonth"": ""07"",
    ""BudgetYear"": ""2104"",
    ""BemsId"": ""123456"",
    ""EmailAddress"": ""XYZSupportEmail@acme.com"",
    ""DeptIdList"": {
      ""DeptId"": [
        ""2"",
        ""3"",
        ""4""
      ]
    }
  }
}");

var client = new HttpClient(Server);
var request = createRequest("api/DeptsAndBelowRate", "application/json", HttpMethod.Post, theContent2);

var client = new HttpClient(Server);
var request = createRequest("api/DeptsAndBelowRate", "application/json", HttpMethod.Post, theContent2);

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
    {
        var answ = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DeptsAndBelowRate>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(answ);
        Assert.IsNotNull(answ.Result);
        //Assert.True(answ.Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: the edited title conveys that wrong question. Code is using Json Formatter but not using object

Answer (score 0):

Changing this:

```
var request = createRequest("api/DeptsAndBelowRate", "application/json", HttpMethod.Post, theContent2);
```

to this:

```
var request = createRequest<StringContent>("api/DeptsAndBelowRate", "application/json", HttpMethod.Post, theContent, jsonFormatter);
```

and using this base method:

```
    // Creates an HttpRequestMessage which includes object content (e.g. Post)
    protected HttpRequestMessage createRequest<T>(string url, string mthv, HttpMethod method, T content, MediaTypeFormatter formatter) where T : class
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = createRequest(url, mthv, method);
        request.Content = new ObjectContent<T>(content, formatter);

        return request;
    }
```

made it work...